# magento add custom tab to frontend product detail page not working

Tags: php, magento

i tried to add custome tab next to product tab in product detail pages but i could not see it , how can i activate it.

what i did

catalog > manage category > add custom layout update >

add below xml and click apply to product

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
<alias>description</alias>
<title>Product Description</title>
<block>catalog/product_view_description</block>
<template>catalog/product/view/mycustomtab.phtml</template>
</action>      
</block>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) I think You should add custom tab to product view handle , or for specific product via admin Manage Product.

2) You can try native magento methods like this:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
   <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
   <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
</block>
```

3) If You want to use Your method You should use reference instead of block, but again only for product

```
<reference name="product.info.tabs">
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="tag">
        <alias>product.tags</alias>
        <title>Product Tags</title>
        <block>tag/product_list</block>
        <template>tag/list.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: try add this to file app/design/frontend/your_package/theme/layout/catalog.xml . Find catalog_product_view and insert my code to content block.